# Compiler vs Assembler

Tags: optimization, assembly, compiler-construction

An assembler takes an assembly code as input and produces machine code as output. So does it mean that an assembler also has to do lexical analysis and syntax analysis on the code?

Like for an example, it will require some way to distinguish between MOV as an instruction and MOVXYZ as a label.

Take for example the following piece of code compatible with 8086.

```
MOV MOVXYZ,013h
MOV BX,023h
ADD BX,MOVXYZ
```

If it does require another round of lexical analysis and syntax analysis, then why at all have the assembly as an intermediate step in compilation?

Edit:

the assembler gets the assembly code as input

```
 MOV AX,MOVXYZ
 ADD AX,BX
```

It essentially is a file with characters. My question is, that if not lexical analysis, how does it distinguish the "MOV" from the "MOVS" ?

Comment: Some assemblers reserve all opcodes, preventing their use as labels. Directives usually have a prefix (`.`). This makes parsing *much* easier than it is for normal programming languages.

Comment: @EOF `Some assemblers reserve all opcodes` Opcodes? You mean mnemonics? Opcode is the part of the **binary instruction** that defines the operation. Mnemonic or opcode mnemonic is the **symbolic name** of the instruction (a string of characters).

Comment: @nrz: Yes, I'm sorry for being a bit sloppy with my terminology.

Comment: Separate backend assemblers are more an unix tradition then something standard. Most normal windows compilers don't use a textual backend by default.

Answer (score 5):

> An assembler takes an assembly code as input and produces machine code as output. So does it mean that an assembler also has to do lexical analysis and syntax analysis on the code?

Yes. Assembler can be thought of as a programming language just like any other, albeit a very low-level one.

> Like for an example, it will require some way to distinguish between MOV as an instruction and MOVXYZ as a label.

Indeed

> If it does require another round of lexical analysis and syntax analysis, then why at all have the assembly as an intermediate step in compilation?

Like you say, it does require analysis, and in fact most compilers *do not* use assembler as an intermediate step but emit binary code directly into some kind of object format, which is later fed to the linker stage.

> As a separate question :if a three-address code is generated as the intermediate form, then its optimisation (done by compiler from three-address code to optimised three-address code) would also require lexical analysis.

Correct, if the 3-address code was actually emitted as text, but in reality it is typically emitted into internal tables in binary form and is therefore effectively already parsed/analyzed.

Comment: gcc uses an assembler "as" as its intermediate step before producing object code. could you provide me with some insight on how "as" converts assembly to machine code?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not possess any insight specific to the `as` assembler.

Comment: Compilers **always** produce assembly, but they usually do in a transparent way if you don't force them to show you the generated assembly.

Answer (score 3):

> So does it mean that an assembler also has to do lexical analysis and syntax analysis on the code?

Only in a very limited way. It has to do it in the sense that is has to extract the opcodes and arguments and so on, which means it is turning a sequence of characters into an internal representation that it can actually work with. But unlike "real parsers", the parsers assemblers often work with plain old string processing instead of finite state machines and things like that. You'll often see things like reading a line, splitting it, interpreting the first part as the opcode - that's not how proper lexical analysis works, but it is effectively extracting tokens.

Removed from the question, but.. yes, assemblers may do some optimization as well. Nothing of the sort you'd expect a compiler to do though. But sometimes there are several ways to translate a mnemonic into an actual instruction, and then it may matter which it chooses, and that choice may be non-trivial. An example of that is branch sizes on x86, there's the 2-byte `7x ofs8` form, which has a limited range, and the 6-byte `0F 8x ofs32`.

In order to find the addresses of instructions and labels (and thus determine which branch you can/have to use) it has to know the size of instruction, however it first needed this information in order to decide the sizes of branches. A common way to resolve this is to assume the small size first, then iteratively change any branch that isn't reaching its target to the bigger variant (this may then cause other branches to get out of range, and so on).

Also some assembly languages have "pseudo instructions", which are written as a simple mnemonic but assembled to two or more actual instructions. The choice of instructions may depend on the operands and so on (in that case it's effectively optimizing for a specific case). Or, more commonly, it could just be a pre-determined macro. MIPS and ARM both have pseudo instructions of the last type.

That was the weird side of assembling, most of what they do is just taking an instruction and encoding it. For example if you write `add eax, edx`, it extracts the tokens `add`, `eax` and `edx`, recognizes that this is an `add` instruction with operands that look like `r32`, and then it can look up in a big table (or giant `switch` or decision tree) how to encode it. Turns out there are two encodings that fit that pattern, `01 /r` and `03 /r`. So you could get `01 D0` or `03 C2`, depending on some choice that the author of the assembler made. If it's assembling 16bit code, it would also emit operand size overrides.

Comment: Nice point about pseudo-instructions, but this is assembler-dependent: some assemblers might not recognize pseudo-instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Some assemblers include some form of higher level directives. For MASM (ML.EXE) 6.11 (released back in the days of MSDOS) and later, there are the dot directives that generate more than one instruction per line of assembly code:

```
        .if     ax == 0 || bx == 0
        ;... conditional code goes here.
        .else
        ;... conditional code goes here.
        .endif
```

These type of directives were popular for reducing the number of labels in source code. There are also directives like .while .break .endw . Scroll down to the conditional control flow section of this web page [ml directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx).

IBM's HLASM also supports similar features: [IBM HLASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_High_Level_Assembler)

Many assemblers also support macros, where a generic sequence of instructions defined in a macro can be generated with a single instance of a macro (optionally with parameters) in source code.

Comment: That is a vendor-specific feature, not portable and not standarized.

Comment: @m0skit0 - Note the initial statement in this answer, "Some assemblers ...". These are very popular assemblers for their platforms, Microsoft MASM / ML for Dos / Windows on X86, and IBM HLASM for IBM mainframes. Many assemblers for other platforms at least include some form of macro functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> So does it mean that an assembler also has to do lexical analysis and
>   syntax analysis on the code?

Yes, parsing and lexical analysis is the same than a high-level language, but usually much simpler, because one instruction in assembly corresponds to one instruction in machine code. Assembly is a human representation of machine code, there is no abstraction layer like in a high-level language (e.g. C).

> then its optimisation would also require lexical analysis

Assembler does no optimization. It takes your code as is and converts to machine code. Compilers on the other hand can optimize your code; the resulting assembly is already optimized.

Comment: then how does the assembler identify the different tokens in a particular instruction like :    MOV AX,MOVXYZ

for the optimisation, i meant conversion of the three-address code to a more optimised form before conversion to final assembly code.

Comment: MOV -> instruction; AX -> first operand, MOVXYZ -> second operand. It's trivial from assembly syntax. And no, assembler does no such optimization.

Comment: i meant optimisation done by the compiler from three address code to optimised three address code before it converts it to assembly code and feeding it to the assembler

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Provide an example. In any case optimization is done by compiler, which is language-dependant, not by the assembler.

Comment: `No because one instruction in assembly corresponds to one instruction in machine code.` That is not true. In x86 many instructions have 2 or more different encodings. See harold's answer for `add eax,edx` example. More examples: `push edx` in 32-bit x86 (IA-32): it can be encoded as (bytes in hexadecimal): `ff f2` (reg/mem encoding) or `52` (reg encoding). In x86-64 some encodings have fixed 64-bit operand size, so for 64-bit operands the bit 3 of REX byte can be 0 or 1. So `mov r14,cr0` can be `41 0f 20 c6` or `49 0f 20 c6`. Most x86 and x86-64 instructions have 2 or more possible encodings.

Comment: @nrz You're right, and so I am. I never said a MOV always corresponds to SAME instruction, you understood me wrong. A MOV instruction is always one instruction in assembly.

Comment: What does the number of instructions have to do with whether or not lexing or parsing are necessary?

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, right, parsing and lexing is necessary, I misunderstood those concepts in english. I edited my answer.